# CoreData data into UITableView in UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, sdk

I have a UITableView inside a UIViewController that is using ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate.

It looks like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> {
}
```

In the .xib I have a UITableView that I need to populate with data stored in CoreData. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'NSFetchedResultsController', here's a good tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/

and Apple Sample Code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913